# NodeJS failure to concatenate string and number

Tags: node.js, express, redis, concatenation

I use this code to get the user's ID saved in the key user:their_email_id.

```
redis.get("user:" + email, function(err, reply) {
    if (reply != null) {
        id = reply;
        console.log(reply);
    }
});
```

This gives me the user's ID in the `id` variable.

Now I use this ID to query the user's hash:

```
redis.hgetall("user:" + id, function (err, reply) {
    console.log(reply);
});
```

Here I get the reply as null. The reason is instead of the key becoming something like:

```
    user:0
```

I'm getting this:

```
   user:undefined
```

Now I know that it successfully returns the ID, and everything is working, except that when concatenating the ID with the "user:" string, it fails.

I also tried using id.toString(), but Express shows method not found.
Why could this be happening? Do I have to require some library?

And how do I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `redis.hgetall` is not called before `redis.get` calls callback where you set the id ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that was exactly the problem. Then I shifted the hgetall in a function and used it as a callback in the get command. :D...
Thanks a lot...